# driver.navigate.back() doesn't work in iOS v12

Tags: appium, appium-ios

We use BrowserStack to run our automated scripts on iPhone XS iOS 12.
For some reason the scripts are failing when the browser is navigated back using `driver.navigate().back();` and following appium error is displayed:

---

> Appium Error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing
>   the command. Original error:
>   this.rpcClient.allowNavigationWithoutReload is not a function

---

Did any one is facing/faced the same problem? The problem is with iOS v12 but not on iOS v11.xx.

Comment: Which driver are you using ?

Comment: @AlImran Using 'RemoteDriver (Webdriver)'